# C# Application contain files and release them when execute

Tags: c#, console-application

My C# application(one single exe) will call `C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe` when running, but not all computer have installed 7-zip, so is there a way that I can copy the whole `7-zip` folder into my application and put it somewhere in run time then call its `7z.exe` ?

Comment: hrm, this would be a pretty unusual solution, options A) put it in your installer, B) use an sdk or nuget instead of the install program, call it straight from code.. [SDK can be found here](https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)

Answer (score 0):

Include the compression lib to your app.
The built-in compression in .NET with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files

Or use with https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/